# Narrow size of inputs in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to narrow the size of input boxes in the horizontal form.

I used `col-sm-4` to make text boxes narrower.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class=" form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">date</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
               <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control" />
           </div>
       </div>    
</form>
```

For big size it works, however when I resize the form and make it smaller, suddenly, the length of input box will stretch and become larger. So for big screens the input will have 230px and for smaller screen it will have 608px

The fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/3YWkd/

I want that the size of text box remain the same during page shrink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class=" form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12 control-label">date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <input name="date" type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

Comment: Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Kvmq2/, when you resize this form and make it shrink, the labels will move to the top of the form (in new row)

Comment: The example i showed you works perfectly: check this link http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/EGXW6/

Comment: it works as it will keep the input box size fix. But it also prevent label to move into new row. Can you please this http://jsfiddle.net/Kvmq2/, resize and you will see labels will move to new row.

Comment: Did you checked my jsfiddle example? All you have to do is to replace col-sm-4 with col-xs-4 and it wont jump the line, what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Dear paula, of course I have checked your links. In bootstrap, the  horizontal form is responsive in the way that the labels will be moved to new row. Your solution keep the label and input in the same row.

Comment: Ok. I think i understand what you want now. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/cLc75/ ? I've updated my answer also.

Comment: Thanks. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the mobile (xs) classes, like so:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <input name="fromDate" type="text" class="form-control" />
 </div>
```

Or just leave the col-xs-4, no need for the sm in this case.

Edit:

Re: your comment, you may use slightly different html, like soQ

```
<div class=" form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label class="control-label" for="fromDate">date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input name="fromDate" type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3YWkd/2/)

Comment: I have test it, when you minimize the form the label and text box positions are switched! You will see a text box first and then the label.

Comment: You asked for the box to remain the same size. The label position was not even mentioned. Check the edit

Comment: thanks! Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Kvmq2/, when you resize this form and make it shrink, the labels will move to the top of the form (in new row)

Comment: Check my edit and the fiddle link, like I said before, this issue was solved.